# Invalid Credential When Sign In Facebook SDK To Firebase/Unity

Tags: facebook, firebase, unity-game-engine

I try to implement Facebook Authentication on my Unity project. So, after experimenting a few things i could make the Email Authentication works fine. But, when i tried to implement the Facebook Authentication it said "Invalid Credential". Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Facebook.Unity;

public class facebookAuth : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake() {
        FB.Init(initCallBack,OnUnityHide);
    }

    void initCallBack(){
        if(!FB.IsInitialized)
            FB.ActivateApp();
    }

    void OnUnityHide(bool show){
        if(show)
            FB.ActivateApp();
    }

    public void facebookLogin(){
        if(FB.IsLoggedIn){
            FB.LogOut();
        }
        var perms = new List<string>(){"email","public_profile"};
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms,facebookResult);
    }
    void facebookResult(ILoginResult result){
        if(FB.IsLoggedIn){
            AccessToken token = result.AccessToken;
            Credential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(token.TokenString);
            firebaseFacebook(credential);
        }
    }

    void firebaseFacebook(Credential token){
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(token).ContinueWith(task=>{
            if(task.IsCanceled){
                Firebase.FirebaseException e = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                errorMessage("Canceled : ",(AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
            }
            if(task.IsFaulted){
                Firebase.FirebaseException e = task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions[0] as Firebase.FirebaseException;
                errorMessage("Faulted : ",(AuthError)e.ErrorCode);
                }
            Debug.Log(task.Result.DisplayName + " " + task.Result.UserId);
        });
    }
    void errorMessage(string str, AuthError error)
    {
        string msg = error.ToString();
        print(str+msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct to my reading. Make sure Facebook is enabled in the Firebase Console and the proper credentials have been filled out:
[image: Screenshot of Firebase console - enabling Facebook]

(I forget this all the time, especially if I have to enter things like the App Secret).

If this doesn't help, it would be useful to have any additional logging (or a copy of the error message) if possible.

--Patrick

Comment: I won't lie: I recorded the current Unity Authentication video and totally got stuck for like 10 minutes because I forgot to turn on Email/Password authentication after switching to a demo account to record >.<

It happens!